# Some questions about async in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm working with emberjs during some time and now I want to refine my understanding of ember's nature.

**Question 1.**
Am I right that the route's `model()` hook is the best place to write asynchronous code (to get all needed data)? Should I try to place all my network requests (or at least most of them) inside routes' models?

**Question 2.**
The component hooks have synchronous nature. Does that mean it's a bad decision to write async code inside hooks?

Say, I have async `init()` hook where some data is calculated and `didRender()` hook where I expect to use that data. When ember calls `init()` it returns a Promise, so it's moved from a stack to a special queue and ember doesn't wait until event loop returns that code back to a stack. So ember runs next hooks, and when `didRender()` is being executed the `init()` hook may not be fulfilled and the expected data may not exist. Is that right?

**Question 3.**
Services hooks should also be synchronous. Because when a service is injected inside a component and is used ember also doesn't wait until the async hook is fulfilled.

Say, I have a shopping cart service with `products` property. The products ids are stored in localstorage and I want to get those products from a server to set them into `products` property.

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { A } from '@ember/array';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
    store: service(),

    init(...args) {
        this._super(args);
        this.set('products', A());
    },

    async loadProducts() {
        const cartProducts = A();
        const savedCartProducts = localStorage.getItem('cartProducts');
        if (savedCartProducts) {
            const parsedSavedCartProducts = JSON.parse(savedCartProducts);
            const ids = Object.keys(parsedSavedCartProducts);
            if (ids.length > 0) {
                const products = await this.store.query('product', {id: Object.keys(parsedSavedCartProducts)});
                products.forEach(p => {
                    p.set('cartQuantity', Number(parsedSavedCartProducts[p.id].qty));
                    cartProducts.pushObject(p);
                });
            }
        }
        this.products.pushObjects(cartProducts);
    },
  ...
});
```

If I call `loadProducts()` from service's `init()` I can't use `this.cart.products` in `controllers/application.js`, for example. Because service is ready, but async `init()` is still executed. So, should I call it in `routes/application.js` `model()` hook?

**Question 4.**
If there is some general component that doesn't refer to any route, but this component needs some data from a server where should I make async requests? Or are computed properties and observers are the only solutions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Good questions here, you’re on the right track!

Question 1: yes, the general rule of thumb is that until you are familiar with things, doing async work in the route hooks (`beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel`) make it easier to think about what is going on. Eventually you may want to start bending the defaults to suit your custom UI needs, but it’s simplest to start with this rule

Questions 2-4: you’re asking several questions here about async code, so will answer here more broadly.

First off, services can do async or not but unless you call those methods from a hook (like a route hook) you are responsible for handling the asynchronous results. For instance, the Ember Data store is a service that **does** return data asynchronously

But if you hit cases where you **do** need to do async in a component, the recommended addon to help with that is Ember Concurrency: http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/introduction/

Ember Concurrency helps solve many of the async bugs and edge cases that you haven’t yet hit, but will, if you start doing async code in components. So I’d highly recommend learning more about it.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for a derailed answer. I've heard about ember-concurrency but never used it. I'll try it for sure. But I wanna clarify,  if component needs some data at the very beginning is it good idea to make requests inside init hook?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine to start an async call in an init hook, I do it regularly. But I also use Ember Concurrency heavily to avoid the problems I would otherwise hit

Comment: I'd like to add some points in


Question 1: My advice would be to load only the necessary data in the route hooks (beforeModel, model and afterModel) and load other data as per the user's activities. eg: load something when user does some action.
It'll make the route load faster.